# How to increase scrollview dynamically based on content

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, scrollview

i have a 10 labels inside scroll view

those 10 labels filled with some data.that data coming from back end. so i can't give sure some time too much of data will come

so i designed like this UI wise

i taken scroll view i mentioned some size like 600 height

scroll view inside one view is there (that view also same height means 600)

in that totally 10 views are there.each view has one label

so for label point of view ,

i applied content hugging priority horizontal 1000 and vertical 1000 also (without hugging priority also i tried)

and i given lines 0 instead of 1

so label is working perfectly like based on content its increasing space

but scroll view not increasing

for example too much data came from back end its show 2 or 3 labels text only

i mean based on scrollview height its showing remaining labels data not showing

so what i need exactly is scroll view also need to increase based on content (view/scrollview need to increase based on content )

i tried to set programatically some height also for scroll view
even though it's not working

can anybody help me about this issue..

thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure your last label has bottom constraint connected with scrollview

Comment: Please propperly format your text. Add some interpunction and remove all the white spacing. It makes your question easier to read and will make it more likely to be answered.

Comment: It is better to use a 'UITableView', were in the mentioned problem will be handled automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto layout, where you use a content view in scrollview, which can be pinned to the scrollview and the height and width constraints given equal to the main view. Then if you want the height to vary dynamically you can give height constraint a low priority compared to the others and hence the content view's height will increase based on its intrinsic size, because of its sub views.

You can check this tutorial,
Hope it will help you..
[Try This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6J22gHORk2I)